# read name of parameter with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have this form given:

```
<item><parameter name="a">3</parameter></item>
```

Is it possible to read the "a" with SimpleXML?

I have already tried $xml->item->parameter->getName(); but it only returns "parameter".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use the `attributes()` method from `SimpleXML`

[SimpleXML::attributes()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

```
echo (string)$xml->item->parameter->attributes()->name;
```

[codepad example](http://codepad.org/djyZMcuW)

---

Alternative solution is using `xpath()`

[SimpleXML::xpath()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

```
$name = $xml->xpath('item/parameter/@name');
echo $name[0];
```

[codepad example](http://codepad.org/w0RvdOMr)

`xpath()` always returns array (or false in case of error), this why you need to assign it to a var, or if you have **php >= 5.4** you can use [array dereferencing](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html)

```
echo $xml->xpath('item/parameter/@name')[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

Read about the SimpleXML function : [attribute()](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/simplexmlelement.attributes.php).

You can use it to get all attributes of an element.
In your case :

```
$attr = $xml->item->parameter->attributes();
$name = $attr['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

see http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

xml:

```
<item>
 <parameter name="a">3</parameter >
</item>
```

php:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach($xml->parameter [0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}

// output
name="a"
```